# Hive table data load with default SerDE

Tags: hadoop, hive

The data is in the following format

a,"b,c",d, e

p,q,"e,r", t

a,s,"t,g", t

I wanted to create a Hive table

Col1, Col2, Col3 , Col4

a   ,    b,c  ,   d   ,  e

p   ,    q    ,   e,r ,  t

a   ,    s     ,  t,g ,  t

As you see above, if the data is encapsulated in double quotes, the comma in between should not be considered in creating the table data. If I use the default SerDe, the double quotes are ignored and b,c is considered as two separate columns.

How do I ensure that the double quote will ignore the comma in between two elements if encapsulated in double quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is possible and feasible, I'd first recommend you explore seeing if the input data can be sanitized in such a way to use something besides commas for field delimiters.  It is always dicey to use a delimiting pattern that may naturally occur in your data.

But if that is not possible, then there is this regular expression-based way to detect quoted commas:

1. First ingest your data into a staging table as single-column rows (the entire line into each row).
2. Detect commas occurring between quotation marks and replace them with an artificial place holder.
3. Split the resulting string using commas as delimiters.
4. Replace the artificial placeholders with the commas that they originally represented.

As a contrived concrete example, I loaded up the following single-column staging table with your data (step #1):

```
hive> DESCRIBE staging;
OK
rawline                     string
Time taken: 0.238 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> SELECT * FROM staging;
OK
a,"b,c",d, e
p,q,"e,r", t
a,s,"t,g", t
Time taken: 0.277 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

The following query then generates the final target table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE test (
    Col1 STRING,
    Col2 STRING,
    Col3 STRING,
    Col4 STRING
  );
INSERT INTO TABLE test SELECT
  regexp_replace(fields[0], "\\[QUOTEDCOMMA\\]", ","),  -- Step #4
  regexp_replace(fields[1], "\\[QUOTEDCOMMA\\]", ","),  -- Step #4
  regexp_replace(fields[2], "\\[QUOTEDCOMMA\\]", ","),  -- Step #4
  regexp_replace(fields[3], "\\[QUOTEDCOMMA\\]", ",")   -- Step #4
FROM (
  SELECT split(  -- Step #2 and #3
    regexp_replace(rawline, "\"([^,]*),([^,]*)\"", "$1[QUOTEDCOMMA]$2"),
    ',') AS fields
  FROM staging
) t;
```

This generates the following final table `test`:

```
hive> SELECT * FROM test;
OK
a   b,c     d        e
p   q       e,r      t
a   s       t,g      t
Time taken: 0.196 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

In this sample implementation, the string `[QUOTEDCOMMA]` is being used as the artificial placeholder for a comma that is found between quotation marks.  The choice was completely arbitrary, and in practice if you go this route you will want to make sure your placeholder does not naturally occur within your data.

Comment: Optionally, you could perform similar sanitization of the data from outside, with sed or something if coming from flat file, or, if you are transferring the data via sqoop, specify the import field delimiters from the other database, if they are in another database that works around the double-quotes vs. commas issue. Hive uses fairly rare field delimiters, \001 or ^A, if i recall correctly, which should be safe in this application.

Comment: @suiterdev Agreed, and a well-taken point.  When I mentioned sanitizing the input data, I was being deliberately general because I don't know the OP's environment, but the points you raise are all potential solutions.

Comment: @rchang - hw do I handle if the number of words split by comma is not 2 and is variable? ie a,"b,c,v,n", t,y   and p,q, "e,r,y", u

Comment: @Vaya At that point the most straightforward options might include upgrading to 0.14 for the CSV support, customizing a UDF, or implementing your own SerDe.  Based on how many different directions that could go, it's probably best to ask it as a new question (different than this one) if you want to go down that route.  Others may know more about it than I do, and it's easier to get others' visibility if it is a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The default text serde in Hive (LazySimple) doesn't support proper CSV semantics. The good news is that in the latest version of hive to date - 0.14.0 - there's a new serde that takes care of exactly that. If you happen to use this version, you can use the CSV serde and specify a double quote as the quote character - leading to proper parsing of the data, as you specify in your question.

Information about the serde and how to use it:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CSV+Serde

Comment: Thanks, this is also an answer but unfortunately I cant upgrade to Hive 0.14.