# hive query csv Text-delimiter issue

Tags: hadoop, hive, delimiter

Trying to import below [data](https://nycopendata.socrata.com/Recreation/Queens-Library-Branches/kh3d-xhq7?) in hive.

name,phone,address

```
Arverne,(718) 634-4784,"*312 Beach 54 Street 
Arverne, NY 11692
(40.59428994144626, -73.78442865540268)*"

Astoria,(718) 278-2220,"*14 01 Astoria Boulevard
Long Island City, NY 11102
(40.77152402451418, -73.92643545073543)*"

Auburndale,(718) 352-2027,"*25 55 Francis Lewis Boulevard
Flushing, NY 11358
(40.76035096822195, -73.79632645819947)*"
```

But address is not coming properly and thus corrupted table data
I guess the issue with line terminated by (taking \n by default, since address is of 3-4 lines), cause when I ran below sample data

```
a,b,"e,f"

x,y,"l,m"
```

with below query

```
create table test(c1 string, c2 string, c3 string)
row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'
with serdeproperties(
"separatorChar" = ",");
```

Its working fine:

test.c1 test.c2 test.c3

```
a   b   c,d

e   f   g,z
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i have worked out.

```
>>> CREATE TABLE Test(name string, phone string, address string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE;
>>> load data inpath 'file.csv' into table Test;

>>>  select name from hiveTest;
+-------------+--+
|    name     |
+-------------+--+
| Arverne     |
| Astoria     |
| Auburndale  |
+-------------+--+
>>> select address from hiveTest;
+--------------------------------------------+--+
|                  address                   |
+--------------------------------------------+--+
| "312 Beach 54 Street Arverne               |
| "14 01 Astoria Boulevard Long Island City  |
| "25 55 Francis Lewis Boulevard Flushing    |
+--------------------------------------------+--+
```

i guess it helps.

Comment: address is truncated. it is suppose to be "312 Beach 54 Street Arverne, NY 11692 (40.59428994144626, -73.78442865540268)"

Comment: Try this:create table my_table(name string, phone string, address string) row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde' with serdeproperties ("separatorChar" ="\t", "quoteChar" = "'", "escapeChar" = "\\") stored as textfile; Change serdeproperties as per the reqirement.

Comment: already tried with these options ("separatorChar" =",", "quoteChar" = "\"", "escapeChar" = "\n") ....again not working..you can get the actual data from this link: https://nycopendata.socrata.com/Recreation/Queens-Library-Branches/kh3d-xhq7?

Comment: Try this out. It worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049674/hive-table-data-load-with-default-serde